# Save image as for example .png by a script

Tags: python, scripting, export, image

My export script should **export** all **images** that the user might have used as textures. I don't have problems collecting the images. I also don't have a problem emulating being in an image-editor. The only thing I couldn't figure out how to do is **how** I can **export** the picture **in any format**. Here is a codesnippet how far I have got so far.

`images` is a list of images to export and they are all part of `bpy.data.images`. `imageEditorArea` is an existing image area because else the script doesn't want to run for some reason. `exportDir` is the directoy where all the images should go.

At this point I remember you that the user should **not** be able to **change the loaction** because he chose the location where the files should go already when he executed my operator

```
prevImage = imageEditorArea.spaces[0].image # want to keep the users selected image around
for image in images:
    imageEditorArea.spaces[0].image = image
    bpy.ops.image.save_as({'area': imageEditorArea}, # emulate an imageEditor
        'INVOKE_DEFAULT', # invoke the operator
        copy=True, # make a copy of the image
        filepath=exportDir + image.name) # export it to this location
imageEditorArea.spaces[0].image = prevImage # reset the image back to the original
```

The problem now is that normally, when you don't hand over a path to export the images to, one can **choose an outputformat** (something like 'BMP', 'JPEG', etc...). I can't figure out how one could achieve this without opening the fileselector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to use a low-level method. The Image class is documented 
[here](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_2/bpy.types.Image.html).

The file format is stored in the attribute
[Image.file_format](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_2/bpy.types.Image.html?highlight=image#bpy.types.Image.file_format).

The Image class offers two methods to save images:

- [save()](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_10/bpy.types.Image.html#bpy.types.Image.save)
- [save_render(filepath,scene=None)](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_10/bpy.types.Image.html#bpy.types.Image.save_render)

So you can probably save your image like this:

```
scene=bpy.context.scene
scene.render.image_settings.file_format='BMP'
image.save_render(filepath,scene)
```

You might try:

```
image.file_format='BMP'
bpy.ops.image.save_as({'area': imageEditorArea}, # emulate an imageEditor
    'INVOKE_DEFAULT', # invoke the operator
    copy=True, # make a copy of the image
    filepath=exportDir + image.name) # export it to this location
```

Comment: first version is better as you don't manipulate the image itself.